# What is the mechanism of calling a function from a template in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to learn Vue.js. I am following a tutorial on this site [`https://scrimba.com/p/pZ45Hz/c7anmTk`](https://scrimba.com/p/pZ45Hz/c7anmTk). From here I am not getting something clear.

Here is the code below and my confusion as well :

```
<div id="app">
        <wizard :name="harry"    :cast="oculus_reparo"     ></wizard>
        <wizard :name="ron"      :cast="wingardium_leviosa"></wizard>
        <wizard :name="hermione" :cast="alohomora"         ></wizard>
    </div>


// emojify returns the corresponding emoji image
function emojify(name) {
    var out = `<img src="emojis/` + name + `.png">`
    return out
}

// cast returns a spell (function) that decorates the wizard
function cast(emoji) {
    var magic = emojify("magic")
    return function (wizard) {
        return wizard + " " + magic + " " + emoji + " " + magic
    }
}


Vue.component("wizard", {
    props: ["name", "cast"],
    template: `<p v-html="cast(name)"></p>`
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        harry    : emojify("harry"   ), 
        ron      : emojify("ron"     ),
        hermione : emojify("hermione")
    },
    methods: {
        // oculus_reparo returns a spell (function) that repairs glasses        
        oculus_reparo: cast(emojify("oculus-reparo")),      
        // wingardium_leviosa returns a spell (function) that levitates an object
        wingardium_leviosa: cast(emojify("wingardium-leviosa")),
        // alohomora returns a spell (function) that unlocks a door
        alohomora: cast(emojify("alohomora"))
    }
})
```

So far what I have got is that, I have created a component named wizard which takes two properties - `name` and `cast`. `name` is getting the value from data, and so far I understand that `cast` is calling the method with a parameter.

So both of them should return their specific image. My first confusion: Where does wizard come from and how is it showing the data.name image? If it is because of the method call in the template then why does emoji return another image?

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim may be I am not clear. There are no errors I am not clear about the code that's all

Comment: try to edit your question to be more clear, and i'm here to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the example is unnecessarily complex for the ideas you're looking to learn.

`wizard` is being globally registered with Vue by `Vue.component("wizard", ...)`. When Vue interprets each `wizard` call in the template it will replace it with `<p v-html="cast(name)"></p>` which is set in the `wizard` component definition. Here `name` gets mapped to the property that is set via `:name=`. `v-html` is just saying to render as html the return value of `cast(name)`, here `cast` is the function property that is passed to the component and not the `cast` function locally defined. Everything after that happens as you would expect where `emojify` returns a template literal that is passed to `cast`, that then returns a function, which combines the emoji and other properties.